# getting values of table column based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have created a table in which I want all the values within the Name columns(which is hidden). I have used the below jquery code which uses `nth-child(4)` for getting all the values, but the issue is that this table is coming from another application, so say if the table is inserting another column in between then the below code wont work. I am having an id for the column header as `name`

Can anyone please tell me any solution for getting the column values based on the class or id.

Als how can we check if the id is present or missing, if id is missing then  apply the below logic

```js
$('#content table tbody tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
  console.log('seee:', $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
        <th id="name" style="display:none">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td style="display:none">jacob</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td style="display:none">jacob</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td style="display:none">lessi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td style="display:none">firoz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td style="display:none">firoz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td style="display:none">firoz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of the `#name` element and then use it in the `nth-child` selector

```js
var ids = $('#name').index();
$('#content table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + (ids + 1) + ')').each(function() {
  console.log('seee:', $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
        <th id="name" style="display:none">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td style="display:none">jacob</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td style="display:none">jacob</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td style="display:none">lessi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td style="display:none">firoz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td style="display:none">firoz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td style="display:none">firoz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:last-child` assuming that the new `td` is being added between the `testX` fields.

Alternatively, you can find the `name` header, get its `index()` and then find the `td` values from there:

```js
var nameTdIndex = $('#name').index() + 1;
$('#content td:nth-child(' + nameTdIndex + ')').each(function() {
  console.log('seee:', $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
        <th id="name" style="display:none">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td style="display:none">jacob</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td style="display:none">jacob</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td style="display:none">lessi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td style="display:none">firoz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td style="display:none">firoz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td style="display:none">firoz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>76</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td style="display:none">messi</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Rory, but in your answer I am Test3 values for $(this).text()